# Property access to in Matlab similar to Python _

Tags: python, matlab

I'm looking to make a class in Matlab which would mimic the following code (inside a class definition) in python, but am unable to figure out the syntax and/or permissions necessary to make it work:

```
@property
def prop(self):
    return self._prop

@prop.setter
def prop(self, value)"
    'some code'
    self._prop = value

def readprop(self)
    self._prop = 'some code'
```

The main point being that the readprop method does not call the setter method, but does set the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution which was a response to my question on Reddit:

```
function set.prop(obj, value)
    caller = dbstack;
    if ~isempty(strained(caller(size(caller,1)).name, 'set.prop')
       'do code'
    end
    obj.prop = value
end
```

This code will check whether the last called function was the setter or another function and act accordingly.

Comment: Or simpler `caller(end)` instead of `caller(size(caller,1))`

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not supported, best thing you could do is hack it using two properties:

```
classdef A < handle
    properties
        prop %external property for get and set values
    end
    properties (Access=private)
        prop_ %property which is really used to store the data
    end
    methods 
        function set.prop(obj,x)
            disp('s');
            obj.prop_=x; %write to the other property instead
        end
        function x=get.prop(obj)
            disp('g');
            %obj.prop=obj.prop_;
            x=obj.prop_;
        end
        function readprop(self)
            self.prop_=42;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work.  The get method calls the set method. Oddly, if you eliminate the second line of the get function you only have the set function calling the get function, so it somewhat acts as I'd hope.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Yes the line was unnecessary, any attempt to read `prop` is redirected to `prop_` thus there is no need to update `prop` as well.